# When two boys have same marks, why subsequent rank is kept blank?

Tags: matrix-rank

Trying to understand when two boys get same marks as follows, subsequent ranks is not awarded it is kept blank; is this correct interpretation in mathematical terms ? 
Given below, Why boy who got 88 marks not awarded 4th rank ?

MARKS/RANK GIVEN...
99/1Rank...
95/2Rank...
90/3Rank...
90/3Rank...
88/5Rank

So, if 3 boys had got 90 marks the boy who got 88 marks would be ranked as 6th , why not 4th ?

Thanks
Rodney

Comment: If I follow you correctly, the boy who received 88 marks is 6th, because there are a total of 5 boys marked better than he. Although the boy’s **mark** is the 4th highest, the boy himself is the 6th boy in the list of boys, arranged by highest-to-lowest marks.

Answer (score 1):

That there is a "tie for third rank" is a misnomer — the tie is for third *and* fourth rank.

It would be more accurate to say that the two boys with 90 marks share third and fourth ranks between them.